# Change material settings of multiple materials

Tags: python, materials, scripting, settings

I have an object with hundreds of materials, and I want to change the blend mode on all of them to opaque. I do not want to go through them individually, so I was wondering if there was a way through the console or somewhere else. I saw this page which was doing a similar things, but it id only changing the nodes. ([Automatically change the properties of multiple materials](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195671/automatically-change-the-properties-of-multiple-materials)) Thank you!

Comment: To clarify: are you asking about a variation on the python scripts you reference?  And by opaque, what parameter on which node (in Shader Editor?) do you want to change (e.g., set Transmission to 0 on Principled BSDF shader node)?

Comment: I am talking about changing this parameter to opaque (https://imgur.com/a/DGOpXqb), it is just for the viewport. And not necessarily a modification of the one I linked, but something that works similarly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What to Do

You can do this in Python with a loop, but what you loop on depends on what materials you want to change.  The key is that eventually you want to set `material.blend_method = 'OPAQUE'` and the problem becomes how you pick `material`.

If, for instance, you wanted to change the mode for *every* material:

```py
for material in bpy.data.materials:
        material.blend_method = 'OPAQUE'
```

Or you might want to change the mode for the *active object*:

```py
object = bpy.context.active_object
for slot in object.material_slots:
    if slot.material:
        slot.material.blend_method = 'OPAQUE'
```

or if you wanted to change the mode on the selected objects, you would use the loop in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/251389/42221)

### How to Do it

There are two easy ways you can go about doing this.

1. Interactive:

   - Open a *Python Console* window and paste the code directly into the window.
2. As a text:

   - Open a text editor
   - click 'New' to create a new text
   - Insert the line `import bpy`
   - Paste the text
   - Click the run button (looks like the 'play' button in the time line.

The first approach is immediate.  The second takes a little more time, but then you can save the text as a Python file and load it again later.

Answer (score 5):

Affects all selected objects

```
for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    for slot in ob.material_slots:
        if slot.material:
            slot.material.blend_method = 'OPAQUE'
```