# Change material settings of multiple materials (TEXTURE_INTERPOLATION)

Tags: python, materials, scripting, settings

I have an object with hundreds of materials, and I want to change the texture Interpolation (if i right mean how it named) on all of them to CLOSED.
I do not want to go through them individually, so I was wondering if there was a way through the console or somewhere else.

I find some similar question from (that i take this text) and try to compilate something *but all go to hell*

```
    import bpy
    for material in bpy.data.materials:
       #bpy.data.materials.texture_slots.add().mapping = 'FLAT'
        mat = bpy.data.materials
        mtex = mat.texture_slots.add()
        mtex.mapping = 'FLAT'
```

i be wronged no mapping, i need interpolation changed

i don't know anything in that, plz someone hero help me!

For meaning this is articles where i take that

[this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118646/add-a-texture-to-an-object-using-python-and-blender-2-8)
[and that](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/251387/change-material-settings-of-multiple-materials)
maybe it can help

[image: that i what to change]
that i what to change

[image: for all that]
for all that

i hope that i explained all right and meaning, *and hope that my hero find me* heheh-he-hehe
*my english is so-oo-ou bad, sorry for this

Comment: THIS
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/172761/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-node-property-value-the-default/181959#181959
AND THIS
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/202371/how-to-change-texture-interpolation-of-many-images-all-at-once I FIND IT!
YEA
i be my hero, i can do all uself maybe my monolog help somebody